# How to print 2 keys from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

`group` is a dictionary and `'Admin Name'` and `'Admin Link'` are keys in the dictionary.

When I execute the following statement, I receive a `KeyError`.

```
print(group['Admin Name','Admin Link'])
```

How can I print the values corresponding to the aforementioned keys?

Comment: Use two expressions, not one. There is no `'Admin Name','Admin Link'` key, only `'Admin Name'` and `'Admin Link'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two subscription expressions, not one. There is no `'Admin Name','Admin Link'` key (a tuple with two strings), only `'Admin Name'` and `'Admin Link'`:

```
print(group['Admin Name'], group['Admin Link'])
```

Subscription on dictionaries does not support multiple keys, because you can use tuples as keys, e.g. `'Admin Name', 'Admin Link'` is a different key from both `'Admin Name'` and `'Admin Link'`:

```
>>> group = {
...     'Admin Name': 'foo',
...     'Admin Link': 'bar',
...     ('Admin Name', 'Admin Link'): 'spam',
... }
>>> print(group['Admin Name', 'Admin Link'])
spam
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
group = {'Admin Name': '<administrator name>', 'Admin Link': '<administrator link>'}
print(itemgetter('Admin Name', 'Admin Link')(group))
```

This outputs:

```
('<administrator name>', '<administrator link>')
```